# Is this plant a Crassula Ovata or a Portulacaria Afra?

Tags: identification, succulents

:)
What plant is this? I tried to compare it to both the Crassula and the Portulacaria but I think it has a bit of both. Also, the pot is of oval shape, is it necessary to have it? or can I switch to a regular one? I initially thought this was a bonsai and that was the reason it was in this pot but apparently it’s not.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Very much looks like Crassula ovata (Jade tree). it looks like a real tree, not just a recently grown cutting. Very hardy with respect to heat and dryness. Not sure about repotting, but likely to be straightforward.

Comment: I think the pot was for aesthetic reasons: to make the plant look more like a bonsai. You should be able to repot it without any issues, as long as the new pot contains drainage holes. Also, do NOT put any gravel on the bottom of the new pot, as this has been shown to DECREASE drainage instead of improving it. See here for more info: https://s3.wp.wsu.edu/uploads/sites/403/2015/03/container-drainage.pdf. Use a soilless mix for cactus instead.